# Laravel 5.1 Blank in Chrome Becuse of XSRF Cookies in Header

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome, cookies, csrf

Sometime when I open my site in Chrome it showing blank/white screen, but when I restart the browser my site working well, then I know the blank screen because of XSRF token that send in header when chrome start request GET to my site, but it's never error in mozilla, this is the example header for XSRF

```
XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkJtSmdiYUFVVXJxK2Q4bkxvaGdqTXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoid3ZBQXBaK2dIVE5DSnBDVnRFZW5vS0hcL1dZaDRENTFNWm1TZjFtT3paU1NicDEwV0RydGM0MGp1Q3Qrdk9rcEZ0S2RDdERBOXNheDl5U0xVUFpwMGd3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiJkMjQ3M2Q3MTlhYmE2MDhkMTg4N2YzZTM5NzNmMjk2MGM1NTEyZWYzNjlhZTgxMjcwOWExY2MyMjIwZDQ5ZjQ0In0%3D; ARRAffinity=7459802e08037292d7e12c172fb9496af377eac0039643a96805d4f72b58b44f
```

my question is, why that XSRF can makes my site blank with no error?
and how to fix this issue,

Thanks

Comment: can you paste the url here?

Comment: @DhavalChheda sorry but the url cannot share to public